# Bug in the Veins-5.2 Version?

Tags: veins

I have downloaded a veins 5.2 from [here](http://veins.car2x.org/download/). When trying to run veins_inet example available in the subprojects folder, I receive an error saying `./veins_inet/veins_inet.h:37:2: error: #error Veins version 5.1 or compatible required`

"Compatible" is defined as

```
#if !(VEINS_VERSION_MAJOR == 5 && VEINS_VERSION_MINOR >= 1)
#error Veins version 5.1 or compatible required
#endif
```

But if I go to the veins-veins-5.2 folder and run `./print-veins-version`, indeed `5.0` gets returned.

Is this a bug? And is it safe just to comment the above codeblock out, so I can run the simulation.

Comment: I hope you imported the sub project and then added veins in reference projects. Please read about compatibility of veins 5.2 on http://veins.car2x.org/download/

Answer (score 0):

No, Veins 5.2 uses `#define VEINS_VERSION_MINOR 2` (see https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5.2/src/veins/veins.h#L36). Maybe you downloaded and old and a new version and got confused as to which one you are using.